# flux query: filter out all records related to one matching the condition

Tags: node.js, filtering, influxdb, flux

I'm trying to filter an influx DB query (using the nodeJS influxdb-client library).
As far as I can tell, it only works with "flux" queries.

I would like to filter out all records that share a specific attribute with any record that matches a particular condition. I'm filtering using the filter-function, but I'm not sure how I can continue from there. Is this possible in a single query?

My filter looks something like this:
`|> filter(fn:(r) => r["_value"] == 1 and r["button"] == "1" )` and I would like to leave out all the record that have the same `r["session"]` as any that match this filter.

Do I need two queries; one to get those `r["session"]`s and one to filter on those, or is it possible in one?

**Update:**

Trying the two-step process. Got the list of `r["session"]`s into an array, and attempting to use the contains() flux function now to filter values included in that array called `sessionsExclude`.

Flux query section:
`|> filter(fn:(r) => contains(value: r["session"], set: ${sessionsExclude}))`

Getting an error `unexpected token for property key: INT ("102")'`. Not sure why. Looks like flux tries to turn the values into Integers? The r["session"] is also a String (and the [example](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/stdlib/universe/contains/) in the docs also uses an array of Strings)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up doing it in two queries. Still confused about the Strings vs Integers, but casting the value as an Int and printing out the array of `r["session"]` within the query seems to work like this:

`'|> filter(fn:(r) => not contains(value: int(v: r["session"]), set: [${sessionsExclude.join(",")}]))'`

Added the "not" to exclude instead of retain the values matching the array...